# Angular factory, how to completely change result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, singleton, factory

I am currently working on Angular and bump into an issue with factories and user login/logout.

Here is an example showing a use case :

An angular application supports user login and logout, as long as user is logged in, it is required the user's messages are loaded inside a MessageList (which is a factory). At first though, I set up an event system to trigger load/reset user messages if the user login or logout from the application. Here is the factory in code :

```
angular.module("Foo").factory("MessageList", MessageList);

MessageList.$inject = ["User"];

function MessageList(User) {
    var _messages;

    User.onLogin(activate);       User.onLogout(function() { _messages = undefined; });

    activate();
    return _messages;

    ///

    function activate() {
        _messages = $http(...);
    }

}
```

Angular factories are singleton, so execute only once. I already noticed it is possible to update some properties of an object (example `_messages.push` will properly return the message list with the new object in angular components depending on `MessageList`). But replacing the whole object does not seem to work (each time `onLogin` or `onLogout` is triggered, I need to completely rewrite `the _messages` object).

Comment: You probably want to change `_messages = $http(...);` to something like `$http(...).then(function (result) { _messages = result });`

Comment: Oh sorry I wrote something to show the main idea and pass those boilerplate code but you make a point here !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your logic like below to achive it:

```
angular.module("Foo").factory("MessageList", MessageList);

MessageList.$inject = ["User"];

function MessageList(User) {
    var _messages;

    User.onLogin(activate);       User.onLogout(function() { _messages = undefined; });

    function activate() {
        _messages.data = $http(...);
    }
    var _messages = {
        activate: activate
    };
    activate();
    return _messages;

}
```

Now the user details will be in the `data` property of the factories return object. Every time a new user logins, you can overwrite the `data` property alone.